# Test service method from mocked controller returning null

Tags: java, mockito, junit-jupiter

I have a `Controller` that calls a `Service` which reads from a global Cache and returns some values.  I'm trying to create a unit test around it, but my service calls keeps returning null.  What am I doing wrong with my mocks???

Controller class

```
public UserController {
  ...
  @Autowired
  private UserService service;

  // GetMapping, etc
  public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllUserProps(){
      // Some setup
      // calling service to get user props
      Map props = service.getUserProps();
      // return it in a ResponseEntity
   }
}
```

Service class

```
public UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
   @Autowired
   private UserCache userCache;

   ...
   @Override
   public Map getUserProps(){
       Map<String, CacheResult> result = userCache.asMap();
       // loop over map and pull out CacheResult by users unique Id
       // Transfer CacheResult to Map<String, Object> and return
   }

}
```

Junit Test

```
public ControllerTest {

   @InjectMocks 
   UserController userController;
   
   @Mock
   UserService userService;
   
   @Mock
   UserCache userCache

   @Mock ...
   @Mock ...

   @Test
   void testGettingUserProps {
      // setup conditions
      ResponseEntity<Object> result = userController.getAllUserProps();
      // results is always null and it's never getting into the service's 
      // method even after I've set mock conditions for the "userCache"
   }
```

}

I've been at this for hours and I cannot seem to get the code to go into `UserServices`'s `getUserProps` method.  What am I doing wrong?`

Comment: Why would the code go into the service method? You're mocking the service. that will result in `null` results from all method calls on it if you don't mock them as well.

Comment: I've previously been able to get into a `Service`s methods from a `Controller`, however for some reason I cannot with this test.  I'm missing something... but I cannot figure it out.  My end goal is to write conditions for the `Cache` and let the `service` and `controller` execute as normal.

Comment: If you want them autowired, you need to run a Spring test (or whatever your DI framework is); but then you can't (or don't need to) mock them.

Comment: I dont want them autowired, I want them mocked so I can set up conditions for them.

My end goal is to set conditions for the cache and then allow the execution to run as it normally would hitting the `controller` which would call the `service` method `getUserProps`.  My condition (when(service.getUserProps()).thenReturn(...)) would then return the values I'd like to test

Comment: Then you need to mock the method calls as well, and you will not enter the actual `UserServiceImpl` method implementation. To do that, you need to set up a test for that class, not the controller.

Comment: "I want the service mocked" and "I want to have the real service called" is a contradiction. When you have `@Mock UserService service`, then `UserServiceImpl` is never loaded nor executed by your test -> there cannot be any call to the cache.

Comment: It can be Spied